# can we have split field of the real number and how i get the extension dimension?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

what the spilt field of  x^3-8?
I think I cannot split the real number,is that correct? 
what about x^3-2 ,is the extension dimension will be either  6 or 3?
In the beginning  I think it will be 3 extension dimension ,since we have three roots. Then I look for the answer it is 6 extension dimension why?

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying. The splitting field of $x^3-8$ is not a subset of the real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $x^3-8$ has the rational root $2$. Divide the polynomial by $x-2$. We get $x^2+2x+4$, an irreducible quadratic. So the splitting field of $x^3-8$ has degree $2$ over the rationals.

For the polynomial $x^3-2$, adjoin $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to the rationals. Since $x^3-2$ is irreducible of degree $3$, the field $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ has degree $3$ over the rationals. The splitting field of $x^3-2$ is not $E$, since $x^3-2$ has some complex roots. Imagine dividing $x^3-2$ by $x-\sqrt[3]{2}$. We get an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$, so its splitting field $F$ has degree $2$ over $E$. It follows that the degree of $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $(3)(2)$.

Comment: so how many extension dimension of x^3-8? is it 6 or 2?

Comment: The answer above says that the dimension (over $\mathbb{Q}$) of the splitting field of $x^3-8$ is $2$. For this fied is just the splitting field of $x^2+2x+4$.