# How many extension dimension of Q field

Tags: extension-field

How many extension dimension of $\Bbb Q(\omega_3,\omega_5)$, $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3},i)$and $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3},\omega_3)$
where $\omega_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$

the first i think 6 extension
the second is three
third is 4

Comment: Let me know if the edit is what you intended. I am not sure if you were thinking about $e$; since $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: no i want 3,and 5 under e

Comment: The usual notation I have seen for that is $\omega_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ and $m$ are coprime, then $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_n,\omega_m)=\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{nm})$ and the degree is $$
[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{nm}):\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(nm)=\phi(n)\phi(m).
$$ 
With $n=3, m=5$ we obtain that $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_3,\omega_5):\mathbb{Q}]=2\cdot 4=8$. For the second one we have
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})]\cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2\cdot 3=6.
$$
The field is the splitting field of $x^3-2$, as you know - see [can we have split field of the real number and how i get the extension dimension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776451/can-we-have-split-field-of-the-real-number-and-how-i-get-the-extension-dimension).
 The last one is for you.

Comment: can u explain please y u said 2*4 since w3 has three element and w5 has 5 element?

Comment: The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_3)$ is $\phi(3)=2$, so it is a quadratic number field. Note that $1+\omega_3+\omega_3^2=0$, so we do not have "three elements" linear independent.